# Combine Redux Reducers without add a new Level to Existing Reducers

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a need to combine new reducer with the existing one, and the store hasn't configured with `combineReducers` yet, so this is the first it'll be configure.

Taking from the [docs' example](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-3-state-actions-reducers#combinereducers), I think this is how it'll be implemented:

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import existingReducers from './reducer';
import newReducer from './new-reducer';

const reducers = combineReducers({
  existing: existingReducers,
  newReducer
});
```

By that approach, now I need to add a new property in entire state which used the `existing` reducer. e.g

from `state.user.email` need to change into `state.existing.user.email`.

Is it possible to use `combineReducers` without adding a new level property?? I don't want to add a new reducer into the existing one anymore.

---

**Existing State**

```js
{
  user: { email: 'abc', ... },
  foo: { ... },
  bar: { ... },
}
```

If using the above approach, I'll get this state

```
{
  existing: {
    user: { email: 'abc', ...},
    foo: { ... },
    bar: { ... }
  },
  newReducer: { ... }
}
```

Expected State when using `combineReducers`

```js
{
  user: { email: 'abc', ... },
  foo: { ... },
  bar: { ... },
  newReducer: { ... }
}
```

Comment: Yes, `combineReducers()` can be used in a way that does not add a new top-level property to your state. Could you please explain or update your question to show what your desired state tree should look like? By showing your desired state shape, I might be able to help you with a solution.